# Реальный пример использования LinkedList

Tags: java, структуры-данных

В каких случаях можно использовать LinkedList, на собеседованиях спрашивают где можно использовать, когда привожу примеру типа как очередь или стек, они говорят что для таких случаев есть свои Queue и Stack

Comment: Пожалуй единственным плюсом LinkedList является константное временя добавления/удаления при использовании итератора, что можно использовать для оптимизации производительности.

Comment: В принципе, если нужно часто удалять первый элемент, то `LinkedList` должен бы выиграть по производительности у `ArrayList`.

Comment: Как бы да, но реальный кейс какой нибудь бы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Каноническим ответом на такой вопрос является следующий:

> `LinkedList` используется если необходимо производить много операций вставки/удаления элементов в середине списка и мало операций доступа к элементу по индексу.

Структура связного списка в таких операциях будет эффективнее массива, на котором основана реализация `ArrayList`, потому что при вставке элементов в середину `ArrayList` физически сдвигаются все последующие элементы.

Но у `LinkedList` есть недостатки по сравнению с `ArrayList`:

1. Потребление памяти на один элемент у `LinkedList` больше, чем у `ArrayList` (для каждого элемента хранятся ссылки на предыдущий и следующий элементы)
2. Доступ к элементу по индексу медленнее (O(n) в худшем случае)

А со следующими задачами обе реализации справляются одинаково:

1. Поиск элемента по значению (в обеих реализациях O(n) в худшем случае)
2. Итерация по элементам (сложность получения следующего элемента O(1) в обоих случаях)

С учётом того что `ArrayList` при вставке сдвигает элементы массива достаточно быстрым нативным методом `System.arraycopy()` ([документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) утверждает, что сложность вставки n элементов в `ArrayList` будет O(n)), я бы рекомендовал в общем случае использовать только `ArrayList`, а к `LinkedList` обращаться разве что в академических целях (например, в бенчмарках).

Comment: Разве при вставке в середину arraylist проигрывает, линкедлист сдвигает все элементы, а arraylist нативно копирует их

Comment: `LinkedList` ничего не копирует. В его основе лежит структура данных "[связный список](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)". Каждый элемент списка хранит ссылки на следующий и предыдущий элементы. При вставке элементов в `LinkedList` просто переписываются ссылки элементов, между которыми вставляется новый элемент. Сам объект `LinkedList` хранит только ссылку на первый и последний элементы, поэтому доступ к элементу по индексу медленный - приходится идти от элемента к элементу по ссылкам. А вот вставка почти бесплатная.

Comment: Но ведь ему надо будет пройти до середины, что займет много времени, тогда как arraylist их копирует с нативными функциями, что очень быстро

Comment: Поиск элемента, после которого нужно вставить новый, в оценке сложности непосредственно вставки не учитывается. Предполагается, что элемент уже найден (например, мы уже дошли до него итератором). Но если рассматривать общую картину, то да, при вызове `LinkedList.add(index, element)`, прежде чем вставить элемент в определённую позицию, `LinkedList` пройдёт по ссылкам от первого до n-го элемента (или от последнего до n-го, если элемент во второй половине списка).